# Pass variable into an object

Tags: javascript, firebase, object

I'm trying to access the value inside a text field and send it to FIREBASE api using their protocol. following is the code in my HTML page (problem code shown as <----):

```html
Phone number: <input type="text" id="phone"> Message: <input type="text" id="say">
<br><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Send</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  function myFunction(number) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'key=AAAAuA5S******');

    var body = `{
      "to": "cVv1_TyGS228********89Cog2qG6j8IF",
      "data": {
        "phone": "98668******",
        "say": document.getElementById("say").value //<---- problem here
      }
    }`;

    const init = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers,
      body
    };
    fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', init)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((text) => {
        // text is the response body
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        // error in e.message
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = e.message;
      });

  }
</script>
```

However, the code breaks at the shown location. It works fine if I hard code the variable (like "some value"). How to access the value from text fields inside the 'body' object. 
Thankyou..

Comment: "the code breaks" — What does that mean?

Comment: @Quentin I was getting an error from server. Anyway, I've figured out my mistake. You can see my solution below

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After messing around for 4 hours, realised the silly mistake I made. (Maria's second solution came in handy). I'm just displaying the corrected part:

```
const body = `{
    "to": "cVv1_**********fXT89Cog2qG6j8IF",
    "data": {
    "phone": $"{document.getElementById("phone").value}",
    "say": $"{document.getElementById("say").value}"  //<--- added the quotations
      }
}`;
```

So that is it. I forgot the simple quotation marks. Adding this answer so that some noob like me might not waste time for such a simple thing in future

Comment: Instead of `${'"'+...+'"'}` you can just write `"${...}"`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand, why your object is a string actually.

You can solve this just by removing string literal (backticks):

```
const body = {
    say: document.getElementById("say").value
}
```

Or by using interpolation:

```
const body = `{
    say: ${document.getElementById("say").value}
}`
```

But if you really want that bad your object to be a string, use JSON.stringify()

Comment: thanks for reply. I've used your second solution. Added my complete answer below

Comment: @DrAnonymous whaaat aree youu dooinggg -__-